# How use look behind regex in this string

Tags: regex

I want to select exponential numbers from behind. I use this regex`(?<=\^)(\d\^\d)` but this regex does not work in some strings. For example, in `4^2^3^2` it selects `2^3`. I want to select `3^2`. https://regex101.com/r/GWMA4G/1 How do I change the regex?

Comment: Just split on the `^` ?

Comment: what do you mean split on the `^` @Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow greater flexibility for possible expressions that follow your exponential numbers, you can add a negative lookahead pattern to ensure that there isn't another `^` that follows:

```
(?<=\^)(\d\^\d)(?!\^)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/GWMA4G/2

Answer (score 1):

Just add `$` at the end, so your regex should be `(?<=\^)(\d\^\d)$`